# PLSQL fazer atualização de um nodo em xmltype

Tags: xml, pl-sql

Tenho de actualizar uma coluna em formato `xmltype` de uma base de dados Oracle.

Basicamente eu só faço `update` da propriedade `valor` se outra propriedade desse nodo a data e hora forem iguais. Ou seja, no código abaixo, eu só faço `update` no nodo `QUAD02` e valor `VALOR12TIND` onde a hora seja 10:12:52

```
<QUAD02 data="18.08.20" utilizador="30768">
    <VALOR71 titulo="N." valor="2"/>
    <VALOR72 titulo="Data" valor="18.08.20"/>
    <VALOR73 titulo="Hora" valor="10:12:52"/>
    <VALOR12TIND titulo="uuu" valor=""/>
</QUAD02>
<QUAD02 data="18.08.20" utilizador="30768">
    <VALOR71 titulo="N." valor="2"/>
    <VALOR72 titulo="Data" valor="18.08.20"/>
    <VALOR73 titulo="Hora" valor="10:15:52"/>
    <VALOR12TIND titulo="uuu" valor=""/>     
</QUAD02>
```

A query que utilizei foi:

```
update doc_g po set grelha = updatexml( grelha, 'GRELHA/quad/VALOR12TIND"/@valor' ,"ssss")
where xmlexists('$p/GRELHA/quad02/VALOR73 [@valor="10:12:52"]' passing po.grelha as "p"
```

O exemplo é proveniente de uma query que faço em Java. 
Tem alguma ideia de como deva proceder?

Comment: Bom dia! Fui fazer um teste no plsql aqui e deu um erro na hora de fazer o parse do seu xml, validei o xml pelo www.xmlvalidation.com e existe um erro na linha 7, é este mesmo o xml?